# Why does Dropbox say "Killed" on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, dropbox

I'm trying to install Dropbox on Arch Linux. I've installed both `dropbox` and `dropbox-cli`, at least to the point of having the binaries.

When I run `dropbox` on its own, it just responds `Killed` in red lettering. When I run `dropbox-cli start`, it prints out:

```
Starting Dropbox... Dropbox isn't running!
Done!
```

Then a `dropbox-cli status` will return `Dropbox isn't running!`.

I'm connected to ethernet.

Where should I go from here?

---

Edit to include strace:

```
futex(0xa10520, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
futex(0x1285920, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0xa104e4, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 158, {1430164659, 469752000}, ffffffff) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0xa10564, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0xa10560, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0xa105a0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
futex(0xa10520, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
futex(0xa104e4, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0xa104e0, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0xa10520, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
futex(0xa104e4, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 164, {1430164659, 469845000}, ffffffff) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0xa10564, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0xa10560, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0xa105a0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
futex(0xa10520, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
futex(0xa104e4, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0xa104e0, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0xa10520, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
futex(0xa104e4, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 170, {1430164659, 469934000}, ffffffff) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0xa10564, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0xa10560, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0xa105a0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
futex(0xa10520, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 0
futex(0xa104e4, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0xa104e0, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0xa10520, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
futex(0xa104e4, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0xa104e0, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0xa10520, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
futex(0xa104e4, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 177, {1430164659, 470056000}, ffffffff) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
futex(0xa10564, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0xa10560, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0xa105a0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
futex(0xa10520, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
futex(0xa104e4, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0xa104e0, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0xa10520, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 1000})  = 0 (Timeout)
pipe([5, 6])                            = 0
fcntl(5, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(5, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fcntl(6, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(6, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fd8e32809d0) = 22277
close(6)                                = 0
read(5, "", 50000)                      = 0
close(5)                                = 0
wait4(22277,  <unfinished ...>
+++ killed by SIGKILL +++
```

Comment: Do you have `strace`?  If so, try running `strace dropbox` and post the output (or at least the last 20 or 30 lines).  (Don't use a comment; supplementary information like that is considered to be *part of the question*, so you should [edit] your question and add information there.)

Comment: Have you tried with sudo?

Comment: I had tried that. I also tried it again just now. And once more. The last time worked! The only problem is that the dropbox folder is now in my root home folder, instead of my actual user's. Is there a possible fix for this?

Comment: You should use -f with your strace

Comment: Processes getting SIGKILL out of the blue are commonly because they eat too much memory, and then the part of the kernel called the Out-Of-Memory killer kills them. Check `dmesg` for messages explaining such a thing.

Comment: Just wanted to add that `dropbox` and `dropbox-cli` are unofficial packages and not part of Arch Linux. Problems with Dropbox running on Linux should ideally be directed towards the Dropbox developers.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on a Gentoo box where `dropbox start` would simply print `Killed`. In my case, a simple

```
rm -rf ~/.dropbox-dist
```

fixed the problem. Another run of `dropbox` then downloaded the correct version of the daemon binary and asked me to log in again, and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this behaviour for quite some time. It seems that arch and gentoo dropbox packages work differently than expected: they are basically wrappers, initial versions that are able to download the most current binary to your $HOME/.dropbox-dist/ and run that, instead. Usually if you simply run dropbox, it launches $HOME/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd and kills the original process. Have you checked `ps -ef | grep dropbox` after launching? Here's what I usually see:

```
$ strace dropbox
....
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fd144c329d0) = 1530
close(6)                                = 0
read(5, "", 50000)                      = 0
close(5)                                = 0
wait4(1530,  <unfinished ...>
+++ killed by SIGKILL +++
Killed
$ ps -ef | grep dropbox
me   1530     1 99 09:05 pts/6    00:00:32 /home/me/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-16.3.27/dropbox /newerversion
```

RE: `dropbox-status` returning `Dropbox isn't running!`: that is a conundrum that would refute my hypothesis, and if I had enough rep to comment instead of answer, to make sure you're running `ps`, I would have done so instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in my machine all weekend. I remote in to my machine at the office.
It turns out that some genius at IT changed the DNS Server name on friday. Try to ping google:

```
ping google.com
```

And if you're not getting anything. This is the problem. You'll have to contact your IT and change the /etc/resolv.conf file accordingly to what they tell you.

Comment: Also, I'm aware this is a late answer. Just put it here in case someone needs it down the road.